# Can't dynamically add new literal to ASP.NET Panel Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls, literals

I'm trying to add dynamically controls to my WebForms control `ASP:Panel` in such way:

1). First of all, I'm defining some **Literals** in such way:

```
Literal paragraphBegin = new Literal();
paragraphBegin.Text = "<p>";
Literal paragraphEnd = new Literal();
paragraphEnd.Text = "</p>";
Literal breakLine = new Literal();
breakLine.Text = "<br />";
```

2). I have already defined **Panel**, which updates its content and I'm adding new items to it, like this:

```
this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(labelUserGuid);
this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(editableUserGuid);
this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(breakLine);
```

3). Literals paragraphBegin && paragraphEnd are adding well, but not the breakLine `Literal` and I don't understand clearly - **why isn't it adding**?

The final problem occurs with the method in CodeBehind: `SetSceneEditableUserInfo()`

- [ASPX MarkUp](http://ideone.com/XYFop5)
- [CodeBehind](http://ideone.com/Jjh929)

And the final result does look like:

[image]

As you see, `Literal`, which implements `<br />` doesn't work at all. So, I also have tried to add some `Literals` firstly to the **.Controls** of `Label` (which is `<span>`, and which I thought will keep `<br />` in its body), but also no success.

What I'm suppose to do, if I want to fix my issue?

Comment: What is event of page where you put your code add literal control? BTW, you should check the page source make sure break line already added and css style of line break, it can be root cause the break line does not display.

Comment: @ToanVo Actually, I'm not adding programmatically any events, if you mean C# events/delegates, and all stuff is adding to my ASPX WebPage by just clicking on some buttons (where standard .Click() events are fired), when the button was fired Panel updates its content.

Comment: @ToanVo Seems to be, you are correct, thanks! The answer, which was added to my question is showing only, that for such stuff it's good to generate new controls with a new random GUID or smth like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(Page.ParseControl("br"));
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but it would work with:

    this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(Page.ParseControl("<br />"));